# Parsing a series of numbers from TypeScript string

Tags: javascript, typescript

Assume:

`str = "Water - 3, Tomatos - 4, Melons - 5, Apples - 6"`.

My goal is to extract the numbers to a number array in order to perform some calculations on them.

Assuming each number is in range 0-9, in `C#` one could use the `int.TryParse` method on each character and parse those numbers into an array.

1) Is there any equivalent for `int.TryParse` in `TypeScript`?

2) What's the optimal way to extract those numbers into an array, assuming a number representation may be longer then 1 character?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on an empty string to get an array of characters. Then you can  [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) each character removing non-numeric characters. Finally you [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each one to convert it to a number.

#### Numbers Between 0 and 9

```js
let str = "Water - 3, Tomatos - 4, Melons - 5, Apples - 6, Pears - 0"

let nums = str.split('').filter(i => parseInt(i) > -1).map(Number)

console.log(nums)
```

#### All numbers

We can use this regex to split on non-word characters (spaces, commas, etc)

```
/\W/
```

```js
let str = "Water - 3, Tomatos - 44, Melons - 5, Apples - 666, Pears - 0"

let nums = str.split(/\W/).filter(i => parseInt(i) > -1).map(Number)

console.log(nums)
```

Comment: Thanks, it will work only for numbers in range 0-9, any straight forward way similar to this one, to do it for any range? Edit: Code Maniac answer does that :D

Comment: I made an update that works for all numbers larger than 0, also your question only asked for numbers between `0-9`: `Assuming each number is in range 0-9`

Comment: look at `2)` in my question. Nevertheless I appreciate your answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**match**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
let str = "Water - 3, Tomatos - 4, Melons - 5, Apples - 6"

let op = str.match(/\d+/g).map(e=> +e)

console.log(op)
```